# I can't turn a FIFO list into a LIFO in my algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement various algorithms to solve a 8 puzzle problem. For those who are not familiar with the problem, there are 3 rows and 3 columns,and a one empty tile, represented by zero here. It looks like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
initial_state = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8]
goal_state = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]


moves = [
    [ (0,1), (0,3) ],
    [ (1,1), (1,0), (1,4) ],
    [ (2,1), (2,5) ],
    [ (3,0), (3,6), (3,4) ],
    [ (4,1), (4,7), (4,5), (4,3) ],
    [ (5,2), (5,8), (5,4) ],
    [ (6,3), (6,7) ],
    [ (7,4), (7,8), (7,6) ],
    [ (8,5), (8,7) ],
]
def find_new_nodes(state):
    return  [ swap_positions(state[:],a,b) for a,b in moves[find_zero(state)] ]

def find_zero(state):
    return state.index(0)

def swap_positions(lis, pos1, pos2):
    lis[pos1],lis[pos2] = lis[pos2],lis[pos1]
    return lis

def BFS(start,goal):

    visited = [] #visited list
    node_queue= [start] #main queue
    visited.append(start)
    while node_queue:
        current = node_queue.pop(0)
        print(current)
        if current == goal:
            return True
       for newnode in find_new_nodes(current):
           if newnode not in visited:
               node_queue.append(newnode)
               visited.append(newnode)

    return False

def DFS(start,goal):

    visited = [] #visited list
    node_queue= [start] #main queue
    visited.append(start)
    while node_queue:
        current = node_queue.pop()
        print(current)
        if current == goal:
            return True
        for newnode in find_new_nodes(current):
            if newnode not in visited:
                node_queue.append(newnode)
                visited.append(newnode)

    return False
```

I changed the pop(0) to pop() so that it is lifo, not fifo. My output of DFS seems like a never ending loop, but it is just a few moves away with this starting list and it reaches the goal with the bfs function in 3 moves. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working? The key characteristic of DFS is that if it tries a bad idea on the first step, it may explore almost the whole solution space before backing up and trying something else.

Comment: I believe it should return a solution when the initial state is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8] when it is just a few moves away from the solution right at the beginning. And the fact that it can not return any solution when I test it with other inputs makes me believe there is something wrong going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong going on.  It is just slow for a couple of reasons.

The first reason for it being slow is that, thanks to it being a DFS, it winds up having to look at all 181440 solvable states before finding the answer.

The second reason is that the line `if newnode not in visited` winds up having to scan the entire array.  So hundreds of thousand of times we need to scan a list that is over 100,000 long, and comparing arrays isn't exactly cheap. This requires tens of billions of operations, which takes a while.

You can eliminate the second problem with switching to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) like this:

```
def DFS(start,goal):

    visited = set() #visited list
    node_queue= [start] #main queue
    visited.add(tuple(start))
    while node_queue:
        current = node_queue.pop()
        print((len(visited), current))
        if current == goal:
            return True
        for newnode in find_new_nodes(current):
            if tuple(newnode) not in visited:
                node_queue.append(newnode)
                visited.add(tuple(newnode))

    return False
```

You can verify by inspection that the algorithm isn't fundamentally changed, but its performance should be improved.  And indeed on my laptop it now manages to finish in about a second.